# What did I do wrong with this combinatorics question?

Tags: combinatorics

I was given the following problem.

> "A teacher wants to choose a captain and vice-captain among 12 volleyball players. In how many ways can she do so?"

I tried to solve it by multiplying 12 by 11 to get 132. However, when I checked the answers of my book it said the answer was 66. I would appreciate if you explained where I went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably the question means just that two players are to be chosen and it doesn't matter which is the captain and which is the vice-captain.  So the number of choices is
$$\binom{12}2=\frac{12\times11}{2\times1}=66\ .$$

However IMHO your interpretation is more sensible, so I would say you were right and the book was wrong.